# How to Add newline after every 3rd element in arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

My program need to add newline after every 3rd element in the arraylist. Here is my input file which contain the following data:

> 934534519137441534534534366, 0796544345345345348965,
>   796345345345544894534565, 734534534596544534538965 ,
>   4058991374534534999999, 34534539624, 91953413789453450452,
>   9137534534482080, 9153453459137482080, 405899137999999,
>   9653453564564524, 91922734534779797, 0834534534980001528, 82342398534
>   6356343430001528, 405899137999999, 9191334534643534547423752,
>   3065345782642564522021, 826422205645345345645621,
>   40584564563499137999999, 953453345344624, 3063454564345347,
>   919242353463428434451, 09934634634604641264, 990434634634641264,
>   40346346345899137999999, 963445636534653452, 919234634643325857953,
>   91913453453437987385, 59049803463463453455421, 405899137534534999999,
>   9192273453453453453758434,

and it goes on to multiple lines.

### Code:

```
public class MyFile {

    private static final Pattern ISDN =Pattern.compile("\\s*ISDN=(.*)");

    public List<String> getISDNsFromFile(final String fileName) throws IOException {

        final Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        final List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher m;
        String line;
        int index = 0;
        try (
        final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);) {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                m = ISDN.matcher(line);
                if (m.matches()) {
                    ret.add(m.group(1));
                    index++;
                    if(index%3==0){
                        if(ret.size() == index){
                            ret.add(m.group(1).concat("\n"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return ret;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would add them all to a List and only add the formatting when you print.  Adding formatting in your data usually leads to confusion.

Comment: Don't use "\n" in this case, use instead `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Comment: can you properly tell me how to do it??

Comment: And what is that `try` block? Where do you catch your exception?

Comment: I did add try{} to get rid of errors. I am going to remove it as code runs perfectly with any trouble. So don't worry about catch.

Comment: @user1803551: Its a try-with-resources feature, which need not require catch expression if the embedded streams don't throw exceptions. Its used so that the streams are closed automatically after their scope ends.

Comment: @AmanAgnihotri Yes I knew what it is :) When I asked "what is that..." I meant it more along the lines of "what do you think you are doing?" because when reading from a file the way he did you should always catch exceptions because you cannot ensure a stream to the file (for many reasons). Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code to read using the "new" Java 7 files I/O and corrected the use of a line separator, along with some formatting. Here I iterate over the list after it was completed. If it is *really* long you can iterate over it while constructing it.

```
public class MyFile {

    private static final Pattern ISDN = Pattern.compile("\\s*ISDN=(.*)");
    private static final String LS = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public List<String> getISDNsFromFile(final String fileName) throws IOException {

        List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher m;

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        for (String line : lines) {
            m = ISDN.matcher(line);
            if (m.matches())
                ret.add(m.group(1));
        }
        for (int i = 3; i < ret.size(); i+=4)
            ret.add(i, LS);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to compare the size of arraylist with index. Just remove that condition and try with this

```
if(index%3==0){                         
   ret.add(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
   }
```

Although I support the comment made by @Peter
`I would add them all to a List and only add the formatting when you print. Adding formatting in your data usually leads to confusion.`