# How to print a list by adding a new line after every 3rd element in a list in java lambda expression?

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8

Suppose I have a list as below

```
Collection<?> mainList = new ArrayList<String>();
mainList=//some method call//
```

Currently, I am displaying the elements in the list as

```
System.out.println(mainList.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(",")).toString());
```

And I got the result as

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
```

How to print this list by adding a new line after every 3rd element in a list in   java, so that it will print the result as below

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

Note: This is similar to *[How to Add newline after every 3rd element in arraylist in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746198/how-to-add-newline-after-every-3rd-element-in-ArrayList-in-java)*.But there formatting the file is done while reading itself.
I want to do it while printing the output.

Comment: It seems to me your question is more fundamental than the output. The real question here is: How do I get the elements in a stream in groups of X? Very surprised not to find something in `Collectors` that does that. You could probably create your own `Collector` that did it, producing `List`s as output.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there's apparently classes in Guava and Apache Commons to do it - http://www.baeldung.com/java-list-split

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `Collectors.groupingBy(predicate).values()` can partition a list into list of sublists. I've built my answer on it.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak: Ah, I should have thought of putting the counter in a container like that.

Comment: I have to wonder, given that `.collect` is a terminal operation and you're apparently only using them for this column creation task, why bother with the overhead of using Streams at all ?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to stick to Java Stream API then your problem can be solved by partitioning initial list to sublists of size 3 and then representing each sublist as a String and joining results with `\n`.

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

final class PartitionListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Collection<String> mainList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i");
        final AtomicInteger idx = new AtomicInteger(0);
        final int size = 3;

        // Partition a list into list of lists size 3
        final Collection<List<String>> rows = mainList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        it -> idx.getAndIncrement() / size
                ))
                .values();

        // Write each row in the new line as a string
        final String result = rows.stream()
                .map(row -> String.join(",", row))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

There are 3rd party libraries that provide utility classes that makes list partitioning easier (e.g. [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-) or [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int))) but this solution is built on Java 8 SDK only.

What it does is:

- firstly we collect all elements by grouping by assigned row index and we store values as a list (e.g. `{0=[a,b,c],1=[d,e,f],2=[g,h,i]}`
- then we take a list of all values like `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]`
- finally we represent list of lists as a String where each row is separated by `\n`

#### Output <kbd>[Demo](https://jdoodle.com/a/6fy)</kbd>

Running following program will print to console following output:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

#### Getting more from following example

[Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782/alnitak) played even more with following example and came up with a shorter solution by utilizing `Collectors.joining(",")` in `.groupingBy` collector and using `String.join("\n", rows)` in the end instead of triggering another stream reduction.

```
        final Collection<String> rows = mainList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        it -> idx.getAndIncrement() / size,
                        Collectors.joining(",")
                ))
                .values();

        // Write each row in the new line as a string
        final String result = String.join("\n", rows);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

#### Final note

Keep in mind that this is not the most efficient way to print list of elements in your desired format. But partitioning list of any elements gives you flexibility if it comes to creating final result and is pretty easy to read and understand.

Comment: JOOI (I'm not an expert on streams) why not use `rows = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> idx.getAndIncrement() / 3))` -  I can't see what's added by the `AbstractMap` and `SimpleEntry` manipulation.   I've tried that and it apparently works for me, but there might be side effects or issues I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Alnitak Good catch, thx! It didn't have any side effects, but it was more verbose due to creating intermediate immutable entries. As you observed it can be simplified by calling `.groupingBy(s -> idx.getAndIncrement() / size)` directly. Thanks for the input!

Comment: you're welcome - also what's the new call to `Collectors.toList()` for?  I've not found it necessary in my experiment - `.groupingBy` already returns a `Map<x, List<String>``

Comment: @Alnitak It can be avoided as well, as `.groupingBy()` uses it when `downstream` is not specified. Thanks again! :)

Comment: For extra fun, use `Collectors.joining(",")` as the `downstream` function within `.groupingBy` and eliminate the `.map(row -> ...)` lambda from the final line.

Comment: and then eliminate the second Stream using `result = String.join("\n", rows.values())`

Comment: @Alnitak Cowabunga! That was a brilliant example of refactoring session - we started with verbose solution and simplified it to a very clever and short implementation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

A side remark : in your actual code, `map(Object::toString)` could be removed if you replace

`Collection<?> mainList = new ArrayList<String>();`  by

`Collection<String> mainList = new ArrayList<String>();`.

If you manipulate `String`s, create a `Collection` of `String` rather than `Collection` of `?`.

---

> But there formatting the file is done while reading itself.I want to
>   do it while printing the output.

After gotten the joined String, using `replaceAll("(\\w*,\\w*,\\w*,)", "$1" + System.lineSeparator())` should do the job.
Iit will search and replace all series of 3 characters or more separated by a `,` character by the same thing ($1-> group capturing) but by concatenating it with a line separator.

Besides this :

```
String collect = mainList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

could be simplified by :

```
String collect = String.join(",", mainList);
```

Sample code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Collection<String> mainList = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i", "j");
  String formattedValues = String.join(",", mainList).replaceAll("(\\w*,\\w*,\\w*,)", "$1" + System.lineSeparator());
  System.out.println(formattedValues);
}
```

Output :

> a,b,c,
>
> d,e,f,
>
> g,h,i,
>
> j

Comment: using string processing on the output looks like a nasty hack to me

Comment: The `replaceAll` seems not clean. Would be good if you could at least elaborate on the usage.

Comment: to elaborate on my comment - the regex is content sensitive, and would need modifying if the individual elements no longer match `\w`, making this code brittle.

Whilst perhaps requiring more code, the grouping of the elements into sets of three should be done first using structured data, and not as a post-processing step.

Comment: @Alnitak, My answer is based on the op requirement. We could also replace `\w` by `\w*`. A code is brittle according to why it is designed. Why adding complexity if it is not required ?

Comment: @Downvoter I may understand that this way of addressing the problem may not be chosen by everyone but it is correct and it works. Please read it :  "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that hasn't been answered here is to create a custom `Collector`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PartitionListInPlace {

    static class MyCollector implements Collector<String, List<List<String>>, String> {

        private final List<List<String>> buckets;
        private final int bucketSize;

        public MyCollector(int numberOfBuckets, int bucketSize) {
            this.bucketSize = bucketSize;
            this.buckets = new ArrayList<>(numberOfBuckets);
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBuckets; i++) {
                buckets.add(new ArrayList<>(bucketSize));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Supplier<List<List<String>>> supplier() {
            return () -> this.buckets;
        }

        @Override
        public BiConsumer<List<List<String>>, String> accumulator() {
            return (buckets, element) -> buckets
              .stream()
              .filter(x -> x.size() < bucketSize)
              .findFirst()
              .orElseGet(() -> {
                  ArrayList<String> nextBucket = new ArrayList<>(bucketSize);
                  buckets.add(nextBucket);
                  return nextBucket;
              })
              .add(element);
        }

        @Override
        public BinaryOperator<List<List<String>>> combiner() {
            return (b1, b2) -> {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            };
        }

        @Override
        public Function<List<List<String>>, String> finisher() {
            return buckets -> buckets.stream()
              .map(x -> x.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
              .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
            return new HashSet<>();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<String> mainList = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i", "j");

        String formattedValues = mainList
          .stream()
          .collect(new MyCollector(mainList.size() / 3, 3));
        System.out.println(formattedValues);
    }
}
```

### Explanation

This is a mutable collector that should not be used in parallel. If your necessities require that you process the stream in parallel you will have to transform this collector to be thread safe, which is pretty easy if you don't care about the order of the elements.

The combiner throws an exception because it is never called since run the stream sequentially.

The set of `Characteristics` has none that interests us, you can verify this by reading the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html)

The `supplier` method will fetch the bucket in which we want to insert the element. The element will be insert in the next bucket that has space, otherwise we will create a new bucket and add it there.

The `finisher` is quite simple: Join the contents of each bucket by `,` and join the buckets themselves with `System.lineSeparator()`

### Remember

Do not use this collector to process

### Output

```
a, b, c
d, e, f
g, h, i
j
```